# application pool recycle complications

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, application-pool

We have a web application which goes down with an exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException`.  We are looking into root cause to fix.

Until then we are performing application pool recycle every week so that this incident does not occur.

Does recycling app pool every week cause any more complications for the website?

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config of your Sitecore site you can set the `MemoryMonitorHook` to clear some memory:

```
<hooks>
  <hook type="Sitecore.Diagnostics.MemoryMonitorHook, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="Threshold">800MB</param>
    <param desc="Check interval">00:05:00</param>
    <param desc="Minimum time between log entries">00:01:00</param>
    <ClearCaches>true</ClearCaches>
    <GarbageCollect>true</GarbageCollect>
    <AdjustLoadFactor>true</AdjustLoadFactor>
  </hook>
</hooks>
```

This basically tells Sitecore to start clearing caches and call the GC when the memory usage is over 800MB.
That way you don't have to manually recycle the app pool.

If it's not the Sitecore site you're worried about consuming too much memory and you have to recycle the app pool because of other applications, it's hard to tell if there's complications. We recycle the app pools as well once a week, we get no resulting issues. Obviously, we are doing it out of business hours and peak time.
If other applications are consuming too much memory, you could try getting them in a different app pool so you won't disturb the website?

Comment: We actually recycle daily, with no ill effects, except for slower load times for the first user(s). Daily could be a bit too high, but having old sitecore sites, just started the practice and it has stuck.

Comment: That's exactly the same reason we do it :-) I believe it shouldn't even be necessary at all anymore at this point.

Comment: Hehe yeah, but I still do find a lot of issues that crop up that a recycle will fix, so I tend to err on the side of caution and recycle daily (ofc on off peak time).

Comment: And that's exactly the reason why I expect our recycles to happen for a long time still ;-)

Comment: sounds great. how 'bout the opposite though? everytime i make a change to the bin folder, it takes the server more than a minute to respond. It seems to me that the app pool is recycling. can i stop it somehow???

Comment: No, all changes to the bin folder and web.config (among others) will recyle the app pool. You might be able to speed up the process though - http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/03/sitecore-startup-time-something-that.html gives a couple of pointers. Another good article is http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Sitecore%20Performance/Optimizing%20Sitecore%206%20and%20later/Optimizing%20Performance%20in%20Sitecore.aspx